# PHP 7.4.18 update: Mysqlnd -- Calling stmt_store_result after fetch now throws an error

Tags: php, mysqli

We have a bunch of websites using a shared MySQLi class.
PHP 7.4 was working with these and no errors were seen to be generated.

Now, [**PHP Bug #80837**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80837) has been fixed with release of [PHP 7.4.18](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.18)

The problem is that this fix means all our websites are throwing this fatal error and I can't see how to fix the error itself.

## The Exception:

> [06-May-2021 08:04:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command 
> now in /usr/local/lib/php/databaseClass.php:169 Stack trace:
> #0 /usr/local/lib/php/databaseClass.php(169): mysqli_stmt->store_result()
> #1 /usr/local/lib/php/databaseClass.php(897): Database->fetchResult(Object(mysqli_stmt), true)
> #2 /home/account/public_html/.../file.php(45): DatabaseObject->getSelect('SELECT (bad_log...', Array, true)
> #3 /home/katemawdsley/public_html/start.php(10): include('/home/account...')
> #4 {main}   thrown in databaseClass.php on line 169

## The Database Class 'fetchResult' method:

```
/***
 * For use with MySQLi->dbiLink Object.
 * Returns the result as an array of KEY=>VALUE pairs from the Database.
 * @param $result mysqli_result object.
 * @return array|mixed
 ***/
private function fetchResult($result)
{
    if ($result instanceof \mysqli_stmt) {
        $result->store_result(); // This is line 169 

        $variables = [];
        $data = [];
        $meta = $result->result_metadata();

        //error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(),true));
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $variables[] = &$data[$field->name]; // pass by reference
        }
        \call_user_func_array([$result, 'bind_result'], $variables);

        $i = 0;
        while ($result->fetch()) {
            $resultsArray[$i] = [];
            foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                $resultsArray[$i][$k] = $v;
                if ($this->numericIndexes) {
                    $resultsArray[$i][] = $v;
                }
            }
            unset($k, $v);
            $i++;
        }
    } elseif ($result instanceof \mysqli_result) {

        $rowNumber = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultsArray[$rowNumber] = $row;
            if ($this->numericIndexes) {
                foreach ($row as $numerical) {
                    $resultsArray[$rowNumber][] = $numerical;
                }
                unset($numerical);
            }
            $rowNumber++;
        }
        $i = 0;
        unset($row, $rowNumber);
    }

    return $resultsArray;
}
```

## The Database Class 'fetchResult' method called from a 'select' method:

```
/***
 *  Function for retrieving SQL query data from the Database
 * @param $sql string the SQL select query
 * @param null $data string|array the data to check in the query with
 * @return array|bool|mixed
 ***/
public function select($sql, $data = null){


    /***
     * Now prepare the SQL
     ***/
    try {
        $query = $this->databaseObject->prepare($sql);

        /****
         * $query is prepared here....
         ***/

         ...

        $query->execute();
    }
    catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
        $this->exceptionalError($ex);
        return false;
    }
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->exceptionalError($ex);
        return false;
    }

    if (\mb_strtoupper($reduce, "UTF-8") !== "NORETURN") {
        if ($query->field_count > 0 ) {
            $query->store_result();
        }
        $this->rowsFound[] = $query->num_rows;
        $output            = $this->fetchResult($query);  // Call to fetch result method
        if ($query->field_count > 0) {
            $query->free_result();
        }
        $query->close();
        unset($query);
        return $output;
    }

    /***
     * NORETURN value so no result to return.
     ***/
    $successValue = $this->rowsAffected[] = $query->affected_rows;
    $query->close();
    unset($query);
    return $successValue;
}
```

## What is the correct work around for how to construct this `fetchResult` method in light of the update?

(As you can tell we were completely unaware of this previous issue and it didn't appear on any error logs so was a surprise)

Comment: Is the `select` method ever called again before the `fetchResult` method is called?

Comment: `FetchResult` is only ever called from within the `Select` method, (if its important this is a central class used simultaneously by many accounts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `store_result()` twice. You can't do that. Once the results have been buffered in PHP, the connection line is free - there are no more results pending to be fetched. Calling `store_result()` the second time will throw "Out of sync" error.

You call it first here:

```
    if (\mb_strtoupper($reduce, "UTF-8") !== "NORETURN") {
        if ($query->field_count > 0 ) {
            $query->store_result();
        }
```

and then here

```
private function fetchResult($result)
{
    if ($result instanceof \mysqli_stmt) {
        $result->store_result(); // This is line 169
```

Remove one usage and you should be fine.

I would recommend working with `mysqli_result` instead. When you call `get_result` it will buffer the results and give you a familiar object that you can work with. This could simplify your abstraction class significantly.

---

Here is how I would refactor this class:

```
public function select($sql, $data = null)
{

    /***
     * Now prepare the SQL
     ***/
    try {
        $query = $this->databaseObject->prepare($sql);

        /****
         * $query is prepared here....
         ***/

        $query->execute();
    } catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
        $this->exceptionalError($ex);
        return false;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->exceptionalError($ex);
        return false;
    }

    $result = $query->get_result();
    if (\mb_strtoupper($reduce, "UTF-8") !== "NORETURN") {
        $this->rowsFound[] = $result->num_rows;
        if ($result) {
            return $this->fetchResult($result);  // Call to fetch result method
        }
    }

    /***
     * NORETURN value so no result to return.
     ***/
    $successValue = $this->rowsAffected[] = $query->affected_rows;
    return $successValue;
}

private function fetchResult(mysqli_result $result)
{
    return $result->fetch_all($this->numericIndexes ? MYSQLI_BOTH : MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```